# React Native TextInput onSubmitEditing triggering on every Key Press

Tags: javascript, react-native

In Code below, the onSubmitEditing event triggers on *every* key press.  Strangely, if I comment out the onChangeText event, onSubmitEditing somestimes seems to trigger, as appropriate, only on return.

Is someone able to explain how I would either, (a) get onSubmitEditing to trigger appropriately even when onChangeText is called, or (b) retrieve the value of the text input in onSubmitEditing event.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
          onSubmitEditing={
            console.log(`onSubmitEditing: ${this.state.text}`)
          }
          placeholder="Enter Text..."
          returnKeyType="done"
          returnKeyLabel="done"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I am using

```
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.1",
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: This seems to work

```
      onSubmitEditing={a => console.log(`onSubmitEditing: ${this.state.text}`) }
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: `onSubmitEditing` takes a `function` as a argument. Before you were passing an expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply because `onSubmitEditing` is a prop that expecting a function call. When you're doing this `onSubmitEditing={console.log('a')}`, you're missing the binding and so the reason it's working after you implemented in arrow function

Comment: This answer works for me but I did not understand your explanation, could you please explain it?